# Is visualization : space :: simulation : time?

Tags: time, space, analogy

I'm trying to find the right word to complete this analogy.

> visualization : space :: w : time?

The closest I could get is "simulation," but is this a good answer?

Comment: See [Specious present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specious_present) the perception time of duration.

Comment: Space : Time :: Consciousness : Reason OR Consciousness : Space :: Reason : Time

Comment: I made an edit mainly for formatting. You may roll back or continue editing.

Comment: [According to Kant](https://www.iep.utm.edu/kandmind/#SSH1ai), space is the form of intuition (outer sense) that makes visual layouts possible, similarly, time is the form of intuition (inner sense) that makes succession possible. Space is the basis of geometry, time is the basis of arithmetic. The analog of "visualization" would be turning a comic strip into a movie, or running a code, i.e. "animation".

Comment: I would suggest "change". Is the perception of change that gives us a before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualization is not necessarily related to space. An *Ames Room*[1] is an example of how perception of space does not depend on vision but on preconceived ideas (*synthetic a priori*?[2]).

In any case, if we do a naive correlation between with perception of space with vision and perception of time, perhaps the term could be **causality**. As visualization corresponds to perception of spatial phenomena, causality corresponds in an equivalent manner to perception of temporal phenomena.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqNm7.jpg
[2] https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-spacetime/

Answer (score 0):

The OP wants to find "w" given the following assumed relationships:

> visualization : space :: w : time

To get more information how visualization relates to space consider this [Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visualization_(graphics)):

> Visualization or visualisation (see spelling differences) is any technique for creating images, diagrams, or animations to communicate a message.

From this the visualization does two things. It communicates a message and it is a technique. Space is neither of these, but a visualization could be seen as a portrayal of an object in space that is useful for communication.

One way to view analogy is as a [shared abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogy#Shared_abstraction):

> Greek philosophers such as Plato and Aristotle used a wider notion of analogy. They saw analogy as a shared abstraction. Analogous objects did not share necessarily a relation, but also an idea, a pattern, a regularity, an attribute, an effect or a philosophy.

Using the shared abstraction view of analogy and noting that visualization relates to space as a portrayal of an object in space that is useful for communication and thinking of an "object in space" like an "event in time", a replacement for "w" could be "simulation". A simulation is a model of a process in time that is useful for communication.  Similarly, "narration", as an alternative, might work as well.

---

Wikipedia contributors. "Analogy." Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, 19 Mar. 2019. Web. 19 Mar. 2019.

Wikipedia contributors. "Visualization (graphics)." Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, 14 Dec. 2018. Web. 19 Mar. 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Visualization : Space :: **Music** : Time

Visualization occupies space, whereas music occupies time.